# Compare two csvs with powershell and take value from one into other

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, compare

I have two CSVs in powershell that I am trying to extract data from and put into a csv. For example:
contacts.csv with First, Last, Email
mailinglist.csv with First,Last,Email

MailingList email is blank, and I need to pull the email addresses from contacts.csv

Mailinglist has some, but not all, of the contacts as contacts.csv. I need to pull the email addresses from contacts.csv only for the rows that have a match in Mailinglist.csv

So far I have:

```
    $contacts = Import-Csv .\contacts.csv
    $mailing = Import-Csv .\mailing.csv

    $compare = $mailing | select $_ | $_ -notcontains $contacts
    $email = $contacts | Select $_ | Where { $_ -contains $compare }
```

$compare gives me the correct First and Last columns. Correct being that it only returns values matching $mailing, not anything else.

The $email variable comes back empty.

Help? I have a spreadsheet with 850 records I would really like to not have to do manually...

Comment: Change `-notcontains` into `-notin` and `-contains` into `-in`, OR swap the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the solution using `Compare-Object`.

```
Compare-Object $contacts $mailing -Property First,Last -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru |
select * -ExcludeProperty SideIndicator
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called a 'left join'. Try searching around for a join (possibly 
 this good explanation from [Join-Object](http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Join-Object/) will help you figure out what you need) in Powershell and you should find some applicable examples.
There are a few types of joins, like '[inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39630404/inner-join-in-powershell-without-sql)' and 'left/right join' as well.

Powershell doesn't have great built-in functions for joining, so you'll likely need a small function or two.

Just by looking at your code though, you may want to try changing:
`Where { $_ -contains $compare }`

To:
`Where { $compare -contains $_ }`